# Show Excel and Word documents in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know that it's possible to read excel and word (modern)file in xml format, but i would like to know if exists a library useful only to present file content in a view... i don't need edit or manipulate files, i need to create a simple viewer.
I searched here for Excel/Word iOS viewer and library but i found nothing useful.

What do you suggest ? Is it possible create a views for these kind of file ?

Comment: use a UIWebview to show the docs.

Comment: Does it works also on remote files in your opinion ? or i have to add file to resources ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use QuickLook framework for generating previews for documents, that can be handled by system (like iWorks or MS Office). See more information about this at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html