# display excel sheet on iphone simulator

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6

```
  I have an Excel file in resource folder.How  to display that Excel sheet in iphone simulator.Can any one help me out in solving.
```

Thanks....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559143/show-excel-and-word-documents-in-ios

May this above link works for you.

Comment: thanks  @ Aaaaa for suggesting the link